# Xcode not recognizing Unit Test

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the following test file. The strange thing is that when I hit CMD+U the test runs perfectly however there are no indications of the file being a test file (i.e. no diamonds on the left side of the code).

[image]

```
import XCTest
@testable import Saba_Center

class SabaCenterTests: XCTestCase {

    var residentAlimVC: ResidentAlimViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! ResidentAlimViewController
        _ = vc.view

    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any tests to test. You need to make a test like the one it scaffolds for you.

e.g.:

```
func testExample() {
    // Put your test code here
}
```

Comment: I did still not working... Here's the log message: The bundle “SabaCenterTests” couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located